# How do I back up my Windows partition from an Ubuntu live CD?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, backup, data-recovery

My Windows partition (C:) is corrupt. I'm booting up from an Ubuntu live CD and trying to copy all the files from C: to my external drive, but the system expands all of the links, producing a projected copy size of 1.8TB (my external drive is just 1TB, and the data in c: is around 700MB).

Then I looked at `dd` and other backup utilities. Anything I looked into, I couldn't figure out whether or not the image would be readable in Windows through any other app.

Has anyone else tried to back up data from a corrupted Windows installation using Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [OSFMount](http://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html) or dd for Windows.

In my case though I simply replaced the drive, booted up again using the LiveCD, mounted the dd (actually ddrescue) image directly from my external drive, then copied what I wanted to the internal drive (I didn't write back the entire image since it came from a failing drive and thus had gaps in it).